# Setting up safari browser window size in protractor

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, protractor

I'm able to set up the window size using `protractor` in `Chrome` using:

```
args: ['--lang=en','--window-size=350,650']
```

So similarly is there a way to set the same in `Safari` using protractor?